# Importing the Attention package in Keras gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attention'

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, installation

As part of my imports, I am importing the AttentionLayer package as follows:

```
from attention import AttentionLayer
```

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attention'
```

I figured this might be because I need to pip install it so I tried based on other answers I found online a few pip installs I tried were:

```
pip install AttentionLayer
pip install Attention 
pip install keras-self-attention
```

All 3 of those give me:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keras-self-attention (from versions: ) No Matching distribution found for....
```

Why am I not getting it to work and how can I fix it?

I have a suspicion that it might be related to setting the pythonpath but I do not have admin rights to edit this at work.

Thank you.

Comment: What Python version are you using? `pip install keras-self-attention` works for me. Do you have a proxy at work?

Comment: I am using python 3.6. I think so, but we have a website where we can download a bunch of packages and I downloaded keras itself works fine as well as a bunch of other keras related things like: from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer 
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

Comment: What is this attention module you want to use, and where do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

try using the name `keras-attention`:

```
pip install keras-attention
```

you can search pip for packages like this:

```
pip search attention
keras-attention (1.0.0)                      - Attention Mechanism Implementations for NLP via Keras
.
.
.
(other stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Install keras-self-attention: `pip install keras-self-attention`
2. Import SeqSelfAttention: `from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention`

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on google collab, this code worked for me on Feb 2021
pip install keras-self-attention

Answer (score -2):

It's because You didn't have attention module, go to this link https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras/blob/master/layers/attention.py and use this attention module. Regards.

Comment: Would be much better to install it using `pip`. It is available when I checked: keras-attention (1.0.0)                      - Attention Mechanism Implementations for NLP via Keras.