# Unable to import AttentionLayer in Keras (TF1.13)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, attention-model

I'm trying to import Attention layer for my encoder decoder model but it gives error.

```
from keras.layers import AttentionLayer
```

or

```
from keras.layers import Attention
```

following is the error
`cannot import name 'AttentionLayer' from 'keras.layers'`
`cannot import name 'Attention' from 'keras.layers'`
Any suggestons?

---

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by upgrading to tensorflow 1.14 and importing it as

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Attention
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use **tensorflow** if you haven't imported earlier

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Attention
```

Comment: I tried that. That gives error as well : `cannot import name 'Attention' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers'

Comment: Maybe this is somehow related to your problem. [importing-the-attention-package-in-keras-gives-modulenotfounderror-no-module-na](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012191/importing-the-attention-package-in-keras-gives-modulenotfounderror-no-module-na)

Comment: I checked it but I couldn't get it to work with that.